# Is there a better way to do CSS classes "within CSS classes"?

Tags: html, css

The best way to ask my question is to lay out a scenario.

Say I have the following markup:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="jack">

    </div>

    <div class="jill">

    </div>
</div>
```

Right, so the way I was taught to affect the child through the parent was with something like this:

```
.box .jack, .box .jill{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

My question stems from my recent learning of responsive CSS, where I've seen lines such as: @media only screen{}. It has (please forgive any botched terminology) CSS listed inside CSS?? (Curly Brackets within Curly Brackets).

Is there a way to affect the aforementioned markup with something like that? Example:

```
.box{
     .jack{
          /*Mooooom, I don't want to go shopping for school clothes*/
     }

     .jill{
          /*Yay, shopping! I need all the new styles!!!*/
     }
}
```

I've experimented a couple times in a JSFiddle, and it didn't work. My hope is that I'm missing some kind of key word or character. Or is this just not possible to affect elements with CSS in this format?

P.S.
I do not know the term of what I am looking for, so Google isn't helping. If you know that this is already answered, please link me to it!

Comment: I came across some CSS like your example the other day and it worked fine for me, can you paste a fiddle?

Comment: You're confusing media queries with CSS preprocessors like SASS and LESS

Comment: You can achieve that using SCSS. But then you'll need a tool like koala...

Comment: @j08691 I was just using media queries as an example of the "bracket within bracket" setup. I just liked the cleaner and more organized way it looked when I read it, and hoped it was possible to do regular CSS like that.

Answer (score 3):

No...there is not.

You can use CSS preprocessors like SASS/SCSS or LESS (and others, Stylus) which make *writing code* easier and quicker but, in the end, they still compile to the same CSS.

[**SASSMeister Demo**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/e0e084a189f2d75b2100)

---

[**SASS Info Link**](http://thesassway.com/)

[**LESS Info Link**](http://lesscss.org/)

[**6 Current Options for CSS Preprocessors**](http://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/) - 11/2014

Comment: Ah, oh well. It wasn't so much necessary as it was that it was easier to read my code formatted like this. Thank you!