# Is there any css class grouping css classes in css 3?

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, stylesheet

I have a css conflict between share point 2013 core css and my css. 
So I want to put all my class under div #s4-workspace But I search about a way to grouping all classes under this div like in media query in css

### => for example

```
 #s4-workspace {

   input, button{css style}
   a,a:hover{css style}
   table{css style}
  .div1{css style}
  .div2{css style}
  .div3{css style}

}
```

---

is it possible in css3.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to do CSS classes "within CSS classes"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305201/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-css-classes-within-css-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to avoid repeating the id like:

```
#s4-workspace   input,
#s4-workspace   button,
#s4-workspace   a,
#s4-workspace   a:hover,
#s4-workspace   table,
#s4-workspace  .div1,
#s4-workspace  .div2,
#s4-workspace  .div3 {
  /* */
}
```

This is called **nesting** and no it isn't possible in CSS Level 3.

Any preprocessor has this feature like LESS and Sass, though.

EDIT: it appears you want the resulting CSS:

```
#s4-workspace   input,
#s4-workspace   button {
  /* CSS styles 1 */
}
#s4-workspace   a,
#s4-workspace   a:hover {
  /* CSS styles 2 */
}
#s4-workspace   table {
  /* CSS styles 3 */
}
#s4-workspace  .div1 {
  /* CSS styles 4 */
}
#s4-workspace  .div2 {
  /* CSS styles 5 */
}
#s4-workspace  .div3 {
  /* CSS styles 6 */
}
```

Same answer: not possible in CSS Level 3 though it can be compiled from a `.less` or `.scss` file (which would be very similar to your example of code). Those 2 preprocessors allow nesting as one of their basic features.

- [LESS nested rules](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules)
- [Sass nesting](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: thanks, I know this way to apply one style for all tags.
But what I need to add more tags and style for each  one under one dive as a parent. like media query => @media {...classes here...}
check it again :
#s4-workspace {

   a {color:#000}
   button {border:1px}
   inbut {background: #fff}

}

Comment: Oh I did 2 things in my example: adding id at the beginning of each selector and merging styles that I thought were commons. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks again for your effort, Now I'm sure it is not possible in CSS3 and I must use .less or .scss.

- Thanks again